# Filter dataframe which contains POSIXct format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have such a dataframe:

```
myData[1:10,]
 [1] "2016-03-18 11:38:40 GMT" "2016-03-18 11:42:03 GMT" "2016-03-18 11:42:13 GMT"
 [4] "2016-03-18 11:45:17 GMT" "2016-03-18 12:33:52 GMT" "2016-03-18 12:33:55 GMT"
 [7] "2016-03-18 12:36:45 GMT" "2016-03-18 12:44:39 GMT" "2016-03-18 12:48:26 GMT"
[10] "2016-03-18 12:58:19 GMT"
```

and I would like to extract one row of this dataframe with this line of code:

```
myData[myData$X.U.FEFF.time==as.POSIXct("2016-03-18 11:38:40",tz="GMT")]
```

but this line of code returns me nothing:

```
Dataframe with 0 Columns und 6010 rows
```

The have the same datatype:

```
  > str(myData[1,1])
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-03-18 11:38:40"
> str(as.POSIXct('2016-03-18 11:38:40',tz="GMT"))
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-03-18 11:38:40"
```

Could you say me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need `,` to subset the rows i.e. `myData[myData$X.U.FEFF.time==as.POSIXct("2016-03-18 11:38:40",tz="GMT"), ]`

Comment: I have tested it also, but this line returns me:`character(0)`